# Alternative phrasing to "getting work done"

Tags: phrases, expressions, disambiguities

I find myself using the phrase **"I need to get some work done"** in a misleading way.

At any given time, I'm working on projects for my employer, projects as a podcaster, projects at my home or just projects I've assigned myself that are more open ended research and development type.

That leaves me with the phrase "I need to get some work done," which gives an impression workaholism as opposed to a curious self-starter.

What's a single phrase or phrasing syntax that'd help me be more aligned with what I want people to convey?

Comment: For a figurative expression (perfectly respectable *idiom* more than "slang"), you might consider *["I've got a lot on my plate"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/plate)*. It's often, but doesn't *have* to be, "too much".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I need some creative space"*

*"I need to be productive"*

*"I want to make some progress on my projects"*

Comment: Great thoughts - here are my responses: 1) feels like it creates more questions than answers 2) I like this phrase but it tends to imply that someone else is being unproductive, which I'm trying to avoid 3) definitely in the right direction.

Comment: This gets close enough. I figured out the right language for me: "I'm building on a project at that time" and/or "I'm digging into a new project."

Answer (score 0):

Phrases and ideas that come up:

"As a curious self-starter, I shape up myself to get my jobs done"

"As a budding creativepreneur, I always strive to advance my projects into next level"

"I always discuss with my clients to produce meaningful works"